# i need a free/cheap hosting or cloud service that has ffmpeg for a twitter bot

Tags: video, cloud

I want to make a twitter bot that splits long videos into shorter 140sec ones to tweet them and i need a cheap(free if possible)hosting or service that has ffmpeg or other video processing tools to host it (also cron jobs)

Answer (score 0):

All main cloud provider have video processing tools and cron jobs.

If you search for the word `video` on https://comparecloud.in/ you will find:

[image]